# Sudden appearance of "Trying to get property of non-object" PHP errors in production

Tags: php, apache, lamp

We have a production Linux, Apache, PostgreSQL, PHP setup that has suddenly started spitting out this error at multiple points in our application and at seemingly random intervals. The code in production has not been updated for 7 weeks, that update being an upgrade to PHP 5.3 (with associated code changes for compatibility).

I restarted Apache yesterday and the errors seem to be less frequent but started up again (and became quite regular). I disabled the APC module also yesterday and that seem to have worked quite well, but now the errors are starting up again.

I'm quite perplexed as the code hasn't changed and the errors are appearing in weird places, e.g.

```
function __destruct() {
    if ($this->startTransaction) <<< exception here
        $this->connection->commitTransaction();
}

if (!is_null($this->timestamp)) { << exception here, timestamp is a private variable
```

How can $this be a non-object if it's being called by the object itself??

What could be the cause of these errors suddenly appearing? Here's the memory stats from `top`:

```
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   6285148k total,  5794020k used,   491128k free,   332644k buffers
Swap:  1048568k total,      764k used,  1047804k free,  4671488k cached
```

Comment: What is the code of `startTransaction`?

Comment: check if this has already been destroyed

Comment: startTransaction is a private property, this is just one example though. I get errors in all sorts of places where the code hasn;'t been touched, i.e. $this->timestamp on another object where timestamp is another private property. It's like these objects just disappear from memory.

Comment: the framework that you are you using may be implicitly destroying the object which is typical with zend

Comment: echo destroy in the destructor to see if its being called twice? if not try adjusting the php memory in your ini

Comment: It appears I've hit https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50027. I'm running automated tests (since we've shifted production to another server) and the first batch saw 4.5% error rate. I then set `zend.enable_gc = Off`, re-ran the tests and haven't seen errors since - even after re-enabling it. I would like to know if disabling/re-enabling this setting somehow resets/clears GC somewhat which would be why the error doesn't show any more.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50027 and resolved by upgrading PHP to a later version (bug fixed in 5.3.4, whereas 5.3.3 is the package in debian).